# how to give imagepath to navigateuri in silverlight mvvm

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

In my Silverlight5 application that using mvvm, need to acheive the below one.
I have the image folder that contains images. How to get the whole image path and assign it to the hyperlinkbutton.

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="Preview"  NavigateUri="{Binding image_value}"
                                                          TargetName="_blank" />
```

but i need to give the path like the following one ,

```
 ("./Images/{0}", String_Value)
```

Help me to achieve this..

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Converter` which will append those strings:

```
public class ImagePathConverter : IValueConverter
{             
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parametr, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var imgPath = "./Images/{0}";
        return string.Format(imgPath, value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parametr, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion

}
```

And `xaml`:

```
<Page.Resources>
   <converters:ImagePathConverter x:Key="imagePathConverter"/>
   ...
</Page.Resources>   

   ...

<HyperlinkButton Content="Preview"  NavigateUri="{Binding image_value, Converter={StaticResource imagePathConverter}}" TargetName="_blank" />
```

---

**I suggest not to hardcode path, but put it into resource file which will give much more flexibility.*

Answer (score 0):

Hai I have found the solution..

```
 <HyperlinkButton Content="Preview" Margin="2"  NavigateUri="{Binding String_Value,StringFormat='http://localhost:23411/ClientBin/Images/{0}'}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TargetName="_blank" />
```

I put this in my code and its Worked well..